What to do if there is no option to change UEFI boot order in BIOS?
I have a fairly old Toshiba Satellite laptop and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS as sole OS on it. I am planning to install Windows 10 or 11 as a secondary OS. After creating a partition and installing Windows on it, I think I have to change the UEFI boot order in BIOS as Windows boot manager makes itself primary boot option. However when I checked my BIOS settings, I saw that Boot mode option is showing UEFI boot but it is greyed out. What should I do?

Reinstall Grub in Ubuntu Live Session

Are you sure that reinstalling grub will make Ubuntu primary boot option?
